# Menu error on website

Tags: html, css, zooming

Menu on my website is moving when I zoom in browser. See pictures bellow.
First menu is ok, but when I zoom in browser links on left side (Naslovnica,Tutorijali, etc..) moves on right side. How can I fix it to stay on the left side?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f9ax.png  - Ok menu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vApHO.png  - Not good

```
<div class="header"><div class="top-menu-block">

    .header{
        height: 50px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(26, 29, 36);
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        top:0%;
        z-index: 99;
        width:100%;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #bdc3c7;
            }





.top-menu-block{
            position: relative;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 99;
            margin-left:3%;         
        }


        .menu-link{
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font: bold 12px/45px Roboto;
            text-transform:uppercase;
            line-height: 45px;
            color: #FFF;
            padding: 0px 19px 3px 0px ;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 99;

        }
```

Comment: Pozdrav, Eldar! Change that margin-left to some fixed px instead of percents. And make width of header fixed too.

Comment: When I put fixed on header, it group all links together.